# incompatible types: cannot be converted to Context

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

I am and getting an error when trying to modify code to handle documents in `Android Nougat`.

> incompatible types: cannot be converted to Context

This is my code

```
    documentViewHolder.preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    File document = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/heyJudeDocuments/" + getItem(position).attachment_id);  // -> filename = maven.pdf 
                    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MessageAdapter.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",document);
                    Intent docIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    docIntent.setDataAndType(path, getItem(position).mime);
                    docIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    docIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

It's the `MessageAdapter.this` part that seems to be wrong. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

use that context(instead of MessageAdapter.this) in Uri

```
 Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context ,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",document);
```

Answer (score 0):

`MessageAdapter` is not a subclass of `Context`. Usually, for what you are doing (starting an activity, presumably), you have access to the `Activity` that you are in, and that is the `Context` to use here.